# How to close popup when esc is pressed without executing cancel method(SweetAlert)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, web, sweetalert

Hi i am providing a method to my cancel button in my SweetAlert popup but when user press esc it executes the cancel event but i just want to close the popup on pressing esc.

Comment: can you expose `js.erb` code

Comment: you can user `timer` option in for closing popup after specefic time

Comment: I want to close the popup only if user press esc without executing the method for cancel button event.